# is it possible to load a ext page using JQuery from a different domain?

Tags: php, jquery

I tried using $.load to load an entire page form the nytimes.com, because i was curious if there is an alternative method to embed entire pages not usinf iframes

my point is to understand how to build something like
twitter or many app like Pulse for ipad and more...

is it possible to load pages with jQuery or php avoiding iframes?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With php, it's trivial - basically just `echo get_file_contents('http://nytimes.com/');`. However, due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you can't access content loaded from other domains in JavaScript. If you control the server you're loading content from, you can however use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) or the [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) trick to remove these restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately due to Security issues this is not possible. There are alternatives tho.

[Load website into DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237707/jquery-load-website-into-div)

Repeat Question.