# Confusing in load external page into a div

Tags: jquery, html, load

I have some divs like:

```
<div id="menu">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="link.htm">next</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

and the script in another page `link.htm`:

```
<div id="data">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="slide.php">Slide</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I want to load `link.htm` page inside the `content` div's, but i'm just know to load some image:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
                        var data = $(this).attr('href');
                        $('#content').html('<img src="'+data+'" />');
                        return false;
                        });
```

how should I change for load external page into the div?

Comment: This seems to have been answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237707/jquery-load-website-into-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load the specific div, `#data`, in the `#content`.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(data+'#data');
    return false;
 });
```

For more information look at the documentation of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/load/