# Load pages via AJAX and execute javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've been searching for a while now, but I can't figure out how to load an entire page via AJAX and still execute all javascript and css.

Mostly I just end up with the plain text without any CSS.
Is there a way to do this? I tried jQuery.get, jQuery.load and jQuery.ajax, but none really work like that.

Comment: you can do it by jQuery.get, jQuery.load and jQuery.ajax. where is your code?

Comment: @Hameed `jQuery('html').load('/page');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a different solution. You may try it with an `iframe`. Use jQuery to append an iframe script including all relevant codes into some part of your page (like some `div`). This may do it for you including CSS, like;

```
$('<iframe src="your_page.html"/>').appendTo('#your_div');
```

Or you may try something like;

```
$('<iframe src="your_page.html"/>').load(function(){
      alert('the iframe is done loading');
}).appendTo('#your_div');
```

Comment: But there is no way of loading the page dynamically into the iframe is there? I need to add some effects, with this solution I don't know if the page is loaded or not

Comment: You may dynamically create iframe with jQuery. Check http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2010/02/dynamically-create-iframe-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 2):

I have solved similar problem as following.

1. Download the webpage over ajax
2. Iterate it over and find any `<script>` and `</script>` tags
3. Get content from within these tags as text
4. Create new `<script>` element and insert there the code
5. Append the tag to your webpage

Another thing is you will need to somehow call the script..
I have done it this way:

I set standardized function names like `initAddedScript` callback which I am calling after appending the script to the page. Same as I have `deinitScript` called when I do not need the code (and its variables,..) anymore.

I must say this is awful solution, which likely means you have bad application architecture so as I have had:)

With css is it the same, but you do not need any handlers. Just append the `style` tag to your documents head.

Comment: Very good explanation, the problem is that it's a fully existing website, so it's rather hard to change the entire structure for this, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the page you load doesn't have any style data, then the external stylesheets must have relative paths that are not correct **relative to the invoking document.** Remember, this isn't an iFrame - you aren't framing an external document in your document, you're combining one document into another.

Another problem is that loading your complete page will also load the `doctype`, `html`, `head`, and `body` tags - which modern browsers will cope with most of the time, but the results are undefined because it's not valid HTML to jam one document into another wholesale. And this brings me to the third reason why it won't work: **CSS links outside of the** `head` **section aren't valid,** and the misplaced `head` section caused by your haphazard document-in-document collage.

What I'd do for compliance (and correct rendering) is this, which would be implemented in the Success callback:

1. Copy all `link` elements to a new jQuery element.
2. Copy the contents of all `script` in the `head` section
3. Copy the `.html()` contents from the loaded document's `body` tag
4. Append the `link` elements (copied out in step 1) to your host document's `head`
5. Create a new `script` tag with your copied script contents and stick it in the `head` too
6. Done!

Complicated? Kind of, I guess, but if you really want to load an entire page using AJAX it's your only option. It's also going to cause problems with the page's JavaScript no matter what you do, particularly code that's supposed to run during the initial load. There's nothing you can do about this. If it's a problem, you need to either rewrite the source page to be more load-friendly or you could figure out how to make an iFrame suit your needs.

It's also worth considering whether it'd work to just load your external CSS in the host document in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
your page div --> load --> www.some-site.com
```

After a quik search the closest solution seems to be the one by "*And*": [Load website into DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237707/load-website-into-div)

You have to run a **web server** and create a `proxy.php` page with this content:

Then your JQuery load() function should be like this:

```
$("#your_div_id").load("proxy.php?url=http://some-site.com");
```

NB. I have tested this solution and it should not load all the CSS from the target page, probably you'll have to recreate them. For example the image files stored on the remote server will not loaded, I suppose due to authentication policy.
You will be also able to view only the target page without the possibility to browse the target site.

Anyway I hope this could be a step forward to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your entire webpage as text using ajax
2. `document.open();
   document.write(this.responseText);
   document.close();`

   OR

   `document.documentElement.outerHTML = this.responseText;`

But you need to change the path of css and js pages in original webpage if the resulting webpage is in another directory.