# Get HTML Content from another website like (http://www.google.com) using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm making an Get call for the URL http://google.com to get the html content of the site, But on the ajax call I'm ending up with the following 2 errors,

Error : GET http://www.google.com/ undefined (undefined)

Error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load google.com. Origin "URL of my local website" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Code for 1st error:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    cache : false,
    url : url,
    dataType : "xml",
    crossDomain : true,
    contentType : "text/html",
    success : function(data){
        alert("success");
    },
    error : function(error){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Code for 2nd error:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(data){
        alert("success");
    },
    error : function(error){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

What settings i need to make to enable the cross domain call,Help would be really appreciated.

I have also tried setting up $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true and $.support.cros = true; before the ajax even this didn't work.
Solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can do that using a third-party app (that uses server get requests).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237707/load-website-into-div) for a relevant answer. You will likely need to have a URL on your server you can call that will return you Google's HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago I created a project that solves this issue. It's open source [on GitHub](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests)

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com', // Or your web page link
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      var headline = res.responseText;
      htmlCodeTextArea.value = headline;
    }
  });
```

To download it use:

```
git clone git@github.com:IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests.git
```

or click [here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests/archive/master.zip).

Then open `index3.html` file.

Comment: @KyleK It's still working for me. For questions/bug reports open [issues here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a cross-domain request which is blocked by most browsers as a security measure. You can only request content from same domain as the script is running, or need the server to recognize your domain and allow the cross-domain request via Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

See more info on this at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy